# Pie chart from several columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas

everyone! I'm trying to make a pie chart from a pandas df but they're all from different columns. Here's what I have:

[image]

I'd like to have a pie where each slice is the approve, disapprove or none column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Issue': ['Issue1', 'Issue2', 'Issue3', 'Issue4'],
    'Approve': [52, 49, 48, 47],
    'Disapprove': [40, 51, 60, 34],
    'None': [7, 8, 9, 10],
})

df.set_index('Issue').plot.pie(subplots=True,  figsize=(20, 10))
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect!